# How to get current workout activity from watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

if my app is in background and if user launch default workout app from watch. Should I get any call backs to my app. or at least we can able get what type workout activity he's doing?.I need to get notification when users starts workout session from Apple Watch. is it feasible to implement this features on my app. Suppose user activate he's workout as swimming.. should we get current activity workout type..